# Django Modelform altering User Input before validation

Tags: json, django, forms, hstore, modelform

iam a beginner with Django and i am having a problem which i am not able to solve so far even that i have some understanding what is not going on.

I have a model with an HStore Field

models.py

## --------

```
class myModel(models.Model):

     myVariable = HStoreField()
```

forms.py

## --------

```
class myModel(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields = (
                  'myVariable',
                  )
```

here is what i am trying to achieve.
I want the user to enter a comma seperated list ob strings in example the user input to the HStore field might be

"""String1, String2, String3, String4 """ (without the quotas)

what iam trying to do is to convert this "list/string" into a JSON conform format as a dictionary, considering the above case it should look like this

{ "String1": "", "String2": "", "String3": "", "String4": "" }

i wrote a function for this. The function logic should work and i know that it dont work because if the is_valid() function is called within the view the clean() function starts after the validation, anyway here is the function.

forms.py on top of the "class meta:"

```
def clean(self):

    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    str_inputTags = cleaned_data.get('act_tags_Hstore')
  
    if str_inputTags:
         
        # Splitting the input String into a list of tags
        list_tags = str_inputTags.split(",")
         
        # Construct JSON Dict string out of the list of tags
        for tag in list_tags:
            str_inputJSON = "\"%s\": \"\", " % (tag)
 
        # Remove the last added comma and space from the string
        str_inputJSON = str_inputJSON[:-2]
        # Add { in front and } to the back of the entered string       
        str_inputJSON = "{" + str_inputJSON + "}"
             
        # Setting the cleaned_data to the newly constructed string
        cleaned_data['act_tags_Hstore'] = str_inputJSON
         
        return cleaned_data
```

Here is the Error i get within the form

> Could not load JSON data.

So far i believe what i am trying to do won't work within the clean method and neither within the clean_field1 method i probably have to do the above operation before the to_python method is called. Because right now the field is validated before my method/clean is called.
But i dont understand how to do this at the moment.

Comment: But... this code couldn't possibly work. Take it outside of the context of the form and you'll see a number of logic errors, not least of which is that you repeatedly re-assign to `str_inputJSON` without concatenating. Anyway, Python has a perfectly good `json` library for creating JSON from text.

Comment: Yeah you are right the loop should read like this        " for tag in list_tags:
            str_inputJSON = str_inputJSON + "\"%s\": \"\", " % (tag) "

Comment: No. What is that even supposed to be? You should not be creating JSON by concatenating text *at all*. Use the `json` module from the standard library.

Comment: The Point is i want the user to enter a comma seperated strings like i mentioned above   """String1, String2, String3, String4 """  but this should be converted into a Dict where i give every String the value of an empty string '' so it looks like this String1: "", String2: "", String3: "" so i dont want to basically convert it to JSON, i also want to add the empty string to that data provided.

Comment: So: `json.dumps({v: v for v in cleaned_data.get('act_tags_Hstore').split(',')})`. Done.

Comment: Thanks for that one! but i guess this doesn't solve the overall problem that the error is "Could not load JSON data." is raised before the clean method is called.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem i had. 
It is right as mentioned in the comments that my routine was not correct. The way i solved it was by adding a charfield with the same name to the form and manipulating the string i get within the clean() function as mentioned above with some corrections.
Thanks everyone and especially Daniel Roseman.